# Best Free Sources for using Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver

Hey everyone, this is my first post up on StackOverflow! WOO! Anyhow, onto my question...

I'm a computer science major in my sophomore year in college, and I'm taking a Web Expressions class since I thought it would be an easy 'A', and I'm already pretty proficient in (X)HTML and CSS. My professor is having us use Dreamweaver for all of our labs, so I thought I'd get my hands on one of the school copies. I've never used Dreamweaver before in my life, always typing out the code by hand.

Basically, I'm asking if there are any well-written, free resources for learning my way around Dreamweaver. If there's already a source on the site here, I apologize for not searching it out. I did a cursory glance around and couldn't really find anything, however I admit that I didn't look incredibly hard.

Comment: If you've being coding by hand, then continue as usual in Dreamweaver's code mode. Most professional developers won't touch the WYSIWYG mode with a ten feet pole...

Comment: Hmm alright. Are there any tools within Dreamweaver's code mode that speed up development? Or no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe has some tutorials here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/

Since you are an experienced web developer already, using Dreamweaver should be very easy for you. It does some code verification and such which will make your life easier. Like someone else said, stick with the code mode and use Dreamweaver like an advanced HTML editor.